# calling a function within itself

Tags: python, mediawiki-api

As part of my quest to learn Python, I'm writing a wrapper over the MediaWiki API to return article texts.

Here's the function to search for an article:

```
def article_search(self, search_terms):
    url = self.article_url % (self.language, search_terms)
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)

    results = tree.xpath('//rev[@contentmodel='wikitext']/text()')
    test_redirect = re.search('\#REDIRECT', str(results))

    if test_redirect:
        redirect = re.search(r'\[\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]\]', str(results))
        go_to = redirect.group(1)
        article_search(go_to)

    else:
        return results
```

The goal of the if-else block is to check to see if the search result actually is trying to redirect us to another page (`if test_redirect`) and then search for the page that we're being redirected to with `article_search(go_to)`. When I run the code on a page that I know doesn't redirect, it works fine. However, when I run it over a page that **does** have a redirect, I get `NameError: global name 'article_search' is not defined`. I get the feeling this is probably a newbie question, but I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

Comment: It is called [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) and you could google for `Python recursive function`

Comment: Show the whole stack trace. Always show the whole stack trace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that `article_search` is part of a class (since you use `self`). In that case you should call it like that:

```
self.article_search(go_to)
```

(assuming it is not a weird staticmethod but a method of an instance)

Comment: If it is a `staticmethod` or `classmethod`, then `self` doesn't belong there. It would point to the class if it's a `classmethod`, but then it should be named `cls` by convention. Also, if it's a `classmethod`, then `self.article_search` should still fix it.

Comment: @jpmc26 Fair enough. I've removed `classmethod` since it would still work, but it might be a weird `staticmethod` (although I doubt it).

Comment: You also need `return` - `article_search` returns a value from the `else` branch.